# Kubuntu - bluetooth device disappeared

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth, detect

My bluetooth device stopped being detected (maybe because of an update). When I want to access the Bluetooth settings it says that no device is available.

It is the same with `hcitool scan` in the terminal:

```
Device is not available: No such device
```

and I don't see it with `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:0084 Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 04f2:b35a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can I fix it? I am running Kubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before posting this issue I tried several reboots without any improvements. However, my Bluetooth device strangely reappeared in the bottom panel this morning and works properly again. This is very strange since I don't think I have changed anything in the settings, but the problem is finally solved anyway.

The problem left the way he came.